# Working with stropheJS library in reactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strophe

I am trying to connect to a XMPP server using StropheJS library but can't figure out the right way to integrate it in my reactJS app. Now I got my code working by exporting Strophe object by adding this line in strophe.js package file in node_modules folder
`module.exports =  Strophe;`
but I don't think this is the right way to go about it. Can someone guide me how to go about it.
In my js file I am importing strophe by adding line:

```
    // This is JS
    import React, { Component } from 'react';    
    import Strophe from "strophe";

    class Login extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          connection: null
        }
      }
      componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
          connection : new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/")
        });
      }
```

I want a way out without modifying the original strophe package file. Here is my complete code if you want to have a look: https://github.com/cravi24/clientApp/blob/master/src/Components/Login.js

Comment: share actual code

Comment: and let me know which version of strophe you are using.

Comment: I am using  version 1.2.4

Comment: Add your changes in strophe library. which file and change

Comment: I modified the strophe.js file only. Added this line in the end of this file:
`module.exports =  Strophe;`

Comment: Try like `import Strophe from "node_modules/strophe";`

Comment: doesn't work. Gives the same error as before: _strophe2.default.Connection is not a constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130358/discussion-between-ravi-and-venkatraman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem with my code. Strophe is a global object in Strophe library and as soon as I import this library in my react app, it becomes part of window object. Hence I need to use it like this :

```
new window.Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/")
```

instead of

```
new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/")
```

Earlier I was expecting the strophe object to be available in my class as local var but since it wasn't exported in the strophe library, I couldn't access it.

Answer (score 0):

> Strophe is primary purpose is to enable web-based, real-time XMPP applications that run in any browser. Client Library which bind to window object.

Use like below to use it in your React View.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Strophe from "strophe";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      connection: null
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      connection: new window.Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/")
    });
  }
```

#### If you want to use it in Node Side. Use [`Node Strophe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-strophe) and below is the code snippet.

```
// Configuration 
var server = 'bosh.my-server.com';
var jid = 'user@my-server.com';
var password = '';

// Requirements 
var strophe = require("node-strophe").Strophe;
var Strophe = strophe.Strophe;

// Set-up the connection 
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'https://' + server + '/http-bind';
var connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);

// Log XMPP 
connection.rawInput = connection.rawOutput = console.log;

// Connect 
connection.connect(jid, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

For another reference,If you import Strophe library from the package and use 
**new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/")** this syntax. For that you need to use **import { Strophe } from "strophe.js";**.
This is how you can use new **Strophe.Connection** without window object.

Comment: Importing library in this way is called "Destructuring in react".

Comment: What is your question, Update your question,

Comment: i haven't asked anything i have replied to the question.